# Sensing acceleration w.r.t. absolute orientation

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

I am trying to make a circuit which can sense acceleration in the X, Y, Z axis. (e.g. movement straight down should be in, say, Z axis - not X and Y)

However, the circuit may not always be mounted straight - so if I want the data to be in line with the axis (i.e. compensate for being wonky), what do I need - can it be done easily? Does it need a magnetometer/gyroscope?

I have also just found inertial measurement units - are these just a combination of gyroscope + accelerometer? Would this do the job?

Comment: Not really programming-related, is it ? Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would need

1. A Controller calibration Environment, where you can calibrate output of your circut in known environment.
2. And Error Corrector which can apply the error estimation or offset estimation from the calibration data to your actual output.
3. Would recommend to use Gyroscope along with accelerometer if you want to measure tilts. This is because Accelerometer data is typically noisy, and too smoothen it you need low pas filter but that takes away accuracy. Here combining with gyroscope data can help.

This [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) give more insight on how to use more then one sensor to get usable data

Comment: So does the gyroscope measure static tilt of the system, or only tilt if the system is moving?

Comment: Static Tilt will be calculated by Accelerometer data, Gyroscope measures when system is moving, when accelerometer data will be quite noisy.

Comment: I see. So if I was only including the gyroscope for static tilt, does this mean there is no need for it? I understood that an accelerometer requires movement? So if it is randomly orientated, how can you determine which direction the movement is in?

Comment: The accelerometer is always acted upon by gravity along its axis. So Assuming a solid block with X and Y plain parallel to ground the gravity on Z axis would be g. So if the accelerometer reports (0,0,g) your device is lying parallel to ground. If its has tilt then a component of gravity will be act on X and Y axis . Now with gyroscope you will know if you are in motion or not, if not the only force which acts on the device is gravity that will enable you to calculate the tilt.

Comment: I see! So I don't actually need anything other than the accelerometer? Perhaps I should make it determine the constant readings to find the orientation.. then just adjust following readings from that?

Comment: In theory yes, but practially for reasonable accuracy and response time you need Gyroscope along with it and use them as sensor fusion.

Comment: Oh right. Response time is not important - I do not need to react quickly - just record it. Does a gyroscope greatly improve the accuracy? I understood that Accelerometers can help improve accuracy of gyroscope by reducing drift, does this work the other way around?

Comment: They both complement each other. Actually if you can tolerate settling time and have Low pass filter on accelerometer data you can do without Gyroscope.

Comment: Ok. Will give it a go with just the accelerometer for now. I thought that there would actually be more with both in one package, but it seems there are few and they are expensive :( Thanks for all your help!